# ASP.NET unicode to hindi not working

Tags: asp.net, unicode, translation

We are getting below json from a web api , we want to show the unicode text in it in hindi language in asp.net label

{"from":"en","to":"mr","text":"How are you?","translationText":"**à¤¤à¥‚ à¤•à¤¸à¤¾ à¤†à¤¹à¥‡à¤¸**"}

the text in bold above if opened in notepad shows in hindi , see screenshot

[image]

but if same text is set in ASP.NET label then it shows as **à¤¤à¥‚ à¤•à¤¸à¤¾ à¤†à¤¹à¥‡à ¤** we have also added content type utf-8 in

why its not coming in Hindi?

We also tried setting lable font to 'Consolas' as per some codeproject article ,we also tried Devnagari custom font but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this?

```
@Html.Raw(((char)hello).ToString())
```

replace hello with your unicode

Comment: We are not using MVC razor , its in ASPX web form